# Category page / archive of all news from certain category

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages

I've been looking for a few hours for instructions on how to view category page on SharePoint. Ordinary list of all news from certain category with pagination on a bottom (or without it - it is not so important).

All tutorials I have found describe how to create category list or how to insert part of news feed from certain category into specific page.

But I couldn't find anything about such elemental thing like category page. How can I do that?